# Put display:inline element inside nested display:block element doesn't work?

Tags: html, css

See this example:

http://jsfiddle.net/aLrfmyqm/

```css
p {
    display: inline;
}
    
em {
    display:block;
}
```

```html
<p> Outer inline <em>Block <p>Inner inline</p></em></p>
```

I expect the `<p>Inner inline</p>` to be inlined with `Block`, however, it starts in a new line. Does anyone have ideas about this? Thanks!

Answer (score 14, accepted):

Your markup is invalid. You are not supposed to nest a `p` element inside `p` element and hence the issue.

From [W3C](http://www.w3.org/TR/html401/struct/text.html#h-9.3.1) :

> The P element represents a paragraph. It cannot contain block-level
>   elements (including P itself).

Check the source and you will get it why it behaves differently than what you expect it to be

[image]

Your browser will actually separate all the tags out and close the `p` elements for you.

So how we fix it? Use the `<span>` element instead of `<p>`

[**Demo**](http://jsfiddle.net/aLrfmyqm/4/)

Comment: I always wondered if this still applies if `p` is made an inline element through CSS: `p { display:inline; }`

Comment: @knittl You can surely make a `p` as `inline` but nesting matters, no matter you change the `display` of an element with CSS, semantically it is incorrect to nest any block level element inside `p` and browser will parse it in a different way and will fix by itself

Answer (score 0):

There are two ways to do this:

1. Convert the p element to div.

```
<div> Outer inline <em>Block <p>Inner inline</p></em></div>
```

2. Or change the css of p to inline-block as:

   p {
       display: inline-block;
   }

view demo :https://jsfiddle.net/sonam185/sahfvhdd/ 
demo with div element : http://jsfiddle.net/sonam185/3c3cyv4z/